# django query all with filtering on the related set?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  # ..


class CustomerTicket(models.Model):
  customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  # ..
```

I want to query **all** customers. And, adding for each customer its ticket if it has one in the date range - so I will get the ticket object only if it is in the given date range, otherwise the ticket field would be null.

Comment: you want customers with tickets ?

Comment: No, I want all of them, adding the ticket as a computed field, which might be null

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from django.db import models

customers = Customer.objects.select_related('customerticket').annotate(
    ticket=models.Case(models.When(models.Q(customerticket__date__gt=date1) & models.Q(customerticket__date__lt=date2), then=models.F('customerticket')))
)
```

And you will get `ticket` as a computed field. Note that when referencing relational fields such as ForeignKey or OneToOneField, F() returns the primary key value rather than a model instance, which means your `ticket` field will have value of the primary key.

Comment: I don't know why but the output is very large with many duplicated rows

Comment: What do you mean by duplicated rows?

Comment: I get the same Customer multiple times

Comment: Do you get duplicates if you run `Customer.objects.all()`?

Comment: I don't. Isn't annotate meant to be used for group by statement?

Answer (score 0):

To get customers with related tickets with one query you can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). To make complex condition you can use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q    
Customer.objects.select_related('customerticket').filter(Q(customerticket__date__range=["2018-04-11", "2018-04-12"]) | Q(customerticket__isnull=True))
```

This will filter data by customerticket date.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I also need to filter by the date field. Edited the question

Comment: Tried this way, it does not query all the customers, this query forces customer to have a ticket. I want to query all the customers, so the filter condition should be **only** on the related field

Comment: @user3599803 just add `or` condition, see my updates.

Comment: It sill gives me only in the date range and not all the Customers, so `isnull` condition does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Use queryset.filter:

```
from django.utils import timezone

Customer.objects.exclude(customerticket=None).filter(customerticket__date=timezone.now())
```

Comment: Same problem as with the above answer

Comment: Edited my answer