# django query model A and exclude some items from related model B

Tags: django, django-models, orm, model

I'm new to Django and I'm facing a question to which I didn't an answer to on Stackoverflow.
Basically, I have 2 models, Client and Order defined as below:

```
class Client(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  # ..


class Order(models.Model):
  Client = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
  is_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  # ..
```

I would like my QuerySet `clients_results` to fulfill the 2 following conditions:

- Client objects fill some conditions (for example, their name start with "d" and they registered in 2019, but it could be more complex)
- Order objects I can access by using the `orders` relationship defined in 'related_name' are only the ones that fills other conditions; for example, order is not delivered and was done in the last 6 weeks.

I could do this directly in the template but I feel this is not the correct way to do it.
Additionally, I read in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/) that Base Manager from Order shouldn't be used for this purpose.
Finally, I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792062/django-query-all-with-filtering-on-the-related-set) relatively close to mine using Q and F, but in the end, I would get the order_id while, ideally, I would like to have the whole object.

Could you please advise me on the best way to address this need?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should use a [**`Prefetch(..)`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) here to fetch the related non-delivered `Order`s for each `Client`, and stores these in the `Client`s, but then in a different attribute, since otherwise this can generate confusion.

You thus can create a queryset like:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import timedelta

last_six_weeks = now() - timedelta(days=42)

clients_results = Client.objects.filter(
    name__startswith='d'
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'orders',
        Order.objects.filter(is_delivered=False, order_date__gte=last_six_weeks),
        to_attr='nondelivered_orders'
    )
)
```

This will contain all `Client`s where the name starts with `'d'`, and each `Client` object that arises from this queryset will have an attribute `nondelivered_orders` that contains a list of `Order`s that are not delivered, and ordered in the last 42 days.